# saving/printing text Android

Tags: android, text, save

I have 2 `TextView`, and 1 `Button`.  I want to be able to click the button and to save the text on the first `TextView` and show the value on the second `TextView`.

I've tried this code:

```
    public void buttonOnClick(){
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    textout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             textout.setText(editName.getText()+"\n"+editEmail.getText());
        }
    });


}
```

But I get an error on 'textout'.   When I clock the red light buble, it says 'create a local variable', field text'.

Comment: anytime you get text from and EditText Object you get the text like so: editName.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
         textout.setText(editName.getText().toString()+"\n"+editEmail.getText().toString());
    }
```

Comment: that works great!  But one more question.  Lets say after I hit save and the text values have changed and i have another textview and i hit save again and want to display the updated text there. But the first one doesn't change, the first text view shows the old text when i hit save the first time. How can i do that?

Comment: @user5560712  If there is one **Button** and two **TextViews** `textView_1` and `textView_2`, you can create some `boolean isNext=false` then make use of some if statements in the **onClick()** method. `if (!isNext){textView_1.setText(...); isNext=true;}else{textView_2.setText(...); isNext=false;}`

Comment: @user5560712 I think now every thing is ok

Comment: after putting that code in, i get 2 errors.  'else with out if'.  Then after (!isNext) '';' expected"

Comment: @user5560712 Those are syntax errors from `boolean isNext=false` try to add the semi-colons since I had forgotten them.It should now look like this  `boolean isNext=false;`.Hope now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stimulates from the fact that `EditText` [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) returns `Editable` Object. It's not a `String` and you can't concat 2 `Editable` Objects.

You have 2 Options:

```
textout.setText(editName.getText().toString() + "\n" + editEmail.getText().toString());
```

And Second you can use [SpanableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(editName.getText());
    sb.append("\n").append(editEmail.getText());
```

The Second options allows you also to decorate the Text and save you the Need to build a `String` which is (maybe) better.